# Rewrite URL for 2 queries

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I can't figure out how to have two queries in a URL rewrite.

I know that the following will allow me to have a single query.

```
RewriteRule ^movie/(.+)$   movie.php?url=$1

example.com/movie/superman
```

but how would i add another query in there?

```
example.com/cinema/vue-sheffield/movie/superman
```

everything i do seems not to work.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean another query? You want the url to look lik `eexample.com/cinema/vue-sheffield/movie/superman` but be forwarded to movie.php?url=$1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your cinema is always sheffield you can do this.

```
RewriteRule ^cinema/vue-sheffield/movie/([^/]+) index.php?movie=$1&cinema=sheffield&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

if not then you can do this

```
 RewriteRule ^cinema/([^/]+)/movie/([^/]+) index.php?cinema=$1&movie=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Then you can have

example.com/cinema/whateverhere/movie/somemovie

Comment: I wouldn't always be the same cinema. I would like to be able to change cinema and movie

Comment: Updated my answer. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

That is not necessarily a query, that depends on the web service you're talking to – the stuff coming after the `?` is the URL parameter list, and you can have multiple URL parameters in there separated by `&`. Usually, the order or parameters doesn't matter, and more often than not, you'll find them in the form `?foo=bar&etc=whatever`.

I'm not sure though what your question on rewrite is.

Comment: I want to be able to format example.com/index.php?cinema=sheffield&movie=superman to read example.com/cinema/vue-sheffield/movie/superman in the address bar